# Two monitors. Menu panel on wrong screen

Tags: lxde, display-settings, display-manager

I have a debian 8 jassie with LXDE. I have a two monitors one from my laptop, second is external 24". **Second monitor is a above my laptop**. If I plug in second monitor he was recognized correctly in

> Menu->Preference->Settings dispaly

So I turn on he as Above, and all works good but Menu Panel is on second monitor nor my laptop. How to move Menu Panel from above monitor to my laptop screen ? [image]

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is quite old question but I bumped into the same problem so I share my way of dealing with it.

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

I do **right click** on the panel and select **Panel Settings**

Then I change the monitor in the **Monitor** dropdown (1 -> 2).

[image]